# How to find a button with selenium webdriver in a bokeh document?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bokeh

I am using python and bokeh to create plots and to enable some simple user interactions (e.g. with buttons). I would like to run the python script with `bokeh serve myapp.py` and use pytest and selenium webdriver to interact with the bokeh document in the browser and test the intended workflows.

Given this application code:

```
# myapp.py
# run this with: bokeh serve myapp.py

from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.io import curdoc

# add a button widget
button = Button(label="Press Me")

# add to the document
curdoc().add_root(button)
```

and this (failing) test code

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# get the served bokeh document
driver.get("http://localhost:5006/myapp")

# find the element, variant 1, this gives a
#
# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
# {"method":"name","selector":"button"}
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("button")
print(inputElement)

# find the element, variant 2, this gives a
#
# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: 
# Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
# inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bk-widget bk-layout-fixed")
```

how do I find / access the button with selenium webdriver?

This is the html-page created / served by bokeh:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Application</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bokeh.min.css?v=f7fe43f4980a82921415acbd60d5fd66" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css?v=e2198c0464ced10f820b120714112595" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bokeh-tables.min.css?v=89abce161b192f3f74677f425212bd62" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=f8e9c08dc7d95ab8b8ffd3109ad0ae0d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=a2dd57b513ce6b5a818fc187fe161f28"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh-tables.min.js?v=290ceee4270c39d8e53f1ffcc71980c6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh-gl.min.js?v=7301df140b8889d43d68cef71bd7a987"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="bk-root">
            <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="29ecc46a-da2b-4518-a6c4-985fbd84dd10"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="application/json" id="7f9e0a64-7083-4961-94b7-d5d415349743">
          {}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {

                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('7f9e0a64-7083-4961-94b7-d5d415349743').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"elementid":"29ecc46a-da2b-4518-a6c4-985fbd84dd10","sessionid":"YMyTvdz3FlXoOoB7DEqz3dED3jKe7zqLj9z7xs9lxlvY","use_for_title":true}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a class to the widget:

```
bt = Button(label="click me", css_classes=["my_button"])
```

then select it:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("my_button")
```

It is the parent div node of the button node.

Comment: Can we not assign an id to a button object? I tried setting id as a keyword argument while instantiating a button, but it doesn't seem to show up when I inspect on a browser.